# Remove HTML Table from Apex String

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

I have a String variable holding HTML Tables. Based on certain conditions I would like to remove the whole table having a particular class.

```
String htmlCode = '<table class="table1"></table><table class="table2"></table>';
```

I would like to remove table having class table2

```
Output: 

String htmlCode = '<table class="table1"></table>';
```

I tried with this regex but this also didnt seems to work for my case as I have nested tables.

```
String cleanedString = htmlCode.replaceAll('<table[^>]*class="table2"[^>]*>.*?</table>', '');
```

Comment: What have you tried already?

Comment: I tried this solution but it didn't work for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48251198/regex-pattern-to-replace-html-in-a-given-text-string

Answer (score 1):

If you need to only remove this specific class, then you can do something like this.

```
String htmlCode = '<table class="table1"></table><table class="table2"></table>';

System.debug(RemoveTableBasedOnClass.removeTableWithClass('table2', htmlCode));
```

---

```
/**
 * Created by Nagendra on 24-05-2023.
 */

public with sharing class RemoveTableBasedOnClass {

    public static String removeTableWithClass(String className, String htmlCode){
        Pattern objPattern = Pattern.compile('<table class="' + className+ '">.*?</table>');
        Matcher objMatcher = objPattern.matcher(htmlCode);
        return objMatcher.replaceAll('');
    }
}
```

Output:

```
20:42:34.21 (27517123)|USER_DEBUG|[5]|DEBUG|<table class="table1"></table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but it seems your approach is not working out for my case as I have nested tables